# How an HTTP Instance knows with WebSocket Instance to call?

Tags: websocket, architecture, cloud-foundry

I'm facing an issue in Cloud Foundry with this scenario:

- A device connects to a WebSocket Instance in Cloud foundry
- Then, only one instance in CF holds the socket connection
- The Angular UI sends a request to the REST instance
- The REST instance has to perform an action on the device

Question:

How do I call the right WebSocket instance to get to the device?

[image: Cloud Foundry with Web Sockets]

Thanks!

Serge.

Comment: You use a private "channel" and a pub/sub database or service (i.e., Redis). Any other solution might add scalability concerns.

Comment: Thanks @Myst! I'm currently trying to register the internal IP address of the instance in the database when the WS opens. The Rest instance then will read this value and open another websocket to transfer the call. What do you think?

Comment: You're welcome. Registering IP addresses and adding connections sounds very complicated when compared to existing pub/sub solutions. I think you're over thinking it, there's no point in re-inventing the wheel. It's easy to identify a user by their user ID (or any other unique identifier) and use that as a Redis "channel". This way, the WebSocket instance "subscribes" (listens) to this unique channel and the REST instance publishes (sends data) to this unique channel. It's simpler than you imagine and it scales very easily across machine boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote, I didn't want to setup a messaging system like RabbitMQ just to send a simple command to a device via a Web Socket. Overkilling!

After searching I finally found out a solution to target the right instance.

1\ When the device opens a web socket toward the WebSocket server, I save the CF App ID + the CF Instance Index in the database in the form of "APP_ID:INSTANCE_INDEX".

You can retrieve this information via this code under nodejs in the CF env. vars:

```
const cfenv = require('cfenv');

let appID = cfenv.getAppEnv().app.application_id;
let instanceIndex = cfenv.getAppEnv().app.instance_index;
```

2\ When the user triggers an action in the Angular UI which will call the REST server, this one receives the command and retrieves the "APP_ID:INSTANCE_INDEX" from the DB for the given device.

3\ Next, I open a WebSocket from the REST server toward the WebSocket server targeting exactly the instance which contains the socket on which the targeted device is connected by adding this HTTP header : "X-CF-APP-INSTANCE":"APP_ID:INSTANCE_INDEX".

```
  // Create WS
  this._wsConnection = new WebSocket(this._serverURL, {
    protocol: 'rest',
    headers: { 'X-CF-APP-INSTANCE': 'APP_ID:INSTANCE_INDEX' }
  });
```

4\ The WebSocket server receives the request from the REST server and processes it with the right device and returns the result to the REST server which will return it to the Angular UI.

Et voila !
Problème résolu !

Comment: This solution results in an extra connection being established each time a REST request is received. You might consider polling/globalizing the peer2peer connections to avoid this extra overhead.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks!

Comment: Be careful when using this. If you sending requests directly to a particular app instance on CF, you are no longer load balancing across your app instances. If you're not careful, you could end up with uneven load and possibly performance issues with specific app instances, if too much load ends up on one instance. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit involved but it's possible. First take a look at getting the [stats for a process](https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.60.0/index.html#get-stats-for-a-process). You can use this with `X-CF-APP-INSTANCE` header to reach out to each instance and see which one has the websocket connection you are looking for.

Comment: I finally registered the App ID + Instance Number in the DB right after the device connection so there is no need to look for it. I used it in the X-CF-CF-APP-INSTANCE in the HTTP header as you mentioned. Thanks! this led me to the solution!

Comment: @LucasBrazi06 glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

> How an HTTP Instance knows with WebSocket Instance to call?

My answer is: they shouldn't.

Managing an internal pool of instance information and user connectivity data can add complexity and become a scalability (and maintainability) frustration.

> How do I call the right WebSocket instance to get to the device?

The best approach, IMHO, is to use a pub/sub database, such as Redis (or a pub/sub service, which is the more expensive solution).

The WebSocket connection instance "subscribes" (listens) to a unique private "channel" (a pub/sub message stream).

The REST connection "publishes" (sends data) to the channel.

If a user is on-line, they will be listening (subscribed) and they will receive the data using a "push" approach (no polling required). If no one is listening, the message will simply disappear into the void.

The WebSocket connection could also subscribe to a public / global channel for global notifications.

This approach creates a separation between the sender / publisher (the REST call) and the receiver (the subscribed WebSocket).

This make scaling very easy, since the pub/sub database (in this example, Redis) will handle any message forwarding required.

This will also allow a single user to connect from different machines (i.e., a laptop and a phone) and receive notifications on both machines without any need to to handle IP addresses and without routing the user to a specific server machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I wanted to avoid to setup a Messaging system just to send a command to a device from the sever. It seems overkilling to me!!!

Comment: @LucasBrazi06 - it might seem like an overkill, but it will be easier to implement than any other solution and it will scale well. Other solutions will end up adding more complexity than the pub/sub approach.